# Access IBOutlet inside dispatch_async block

Tags: ios, objective-c, scope, block

it doesn't hide label if I call inside dispatch blocks:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Here your non-main thread.
        [self.loading setHidden:NO];


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Here you returns to main thread.
            [self.loading setHidden:NO];
        });
    });
```

This works, but still not hiding:

```
 [self.loading setHidden:NO];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Here your non-main thread.



        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Here you returns to main thread.
            [self.loading setHidden:NO];
        });
    });
```

How can I access to IBOutlets inside blocks?

Comment: For first example is inadvisable, because you're trying to update UI elements from the background queue. Your second example (if you `setHidden:YES`) is more promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never calling `setHidden:YES` which would hide it. Plus, anything you do to the interface, you should do it on the main thread.